# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null in angular5-data-table angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I use `angular5-data-table` to display my participants. Recently, I started to have errors in searching or filtering the table. The error is :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

I don't know why I have `null`. It's very strange that I didn't have any problems like last week.

My search or filter html code is :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Search by first name" #query (keyup)="searchParticipant(query.value)" [(ngModel)]="filter.name">
```

And my component.ts code is :

```
searchParticipant(query: string) {
  const filteredParticipants = (query) ?
  this.participants.filter(p => p.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) :
  this.participants;
  this.initializeTable(filteredParticipants);
}
```

I am able to list all participants, able to navigate pages and sorting. However, filtering is throwing that error above. I  refactored code and looked at their websites but no luck so far. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the full component.ts file. Please note that instead of `Participant`, I use `Member` in here. But I have the same problem.

```
export class MembersListComponent implements OnInit {
  members: Member[];
  totalMembers: any;

  items: Member[] = [];
  itemCount: number;
  filter: any = {};
  tableResource: DataTableResource<Member>;

  allMembers: Member[];

  constructor(private memberService: MemberService, private alertifyService: AlertifyService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMembers();
  }

  private initializeTable(members: Member[]) {
    this.tableResource = new DataTableResource(members);
    this.tableResource.query({ offset: 0 }).then(items => this.items = items);
    this.tableResource.count().then(count => this.itemCount = count);
 }

  reloadItems(params: any) {
    if (!this.tableResource) { return; }
    this.tableResource.query(params).then(items => this.items = items);
  }

  loadMembers() {
    this.memberService.getAllMembers().subscribe((members: Member[]) => {
      this.members = members;
      this.initializeTable(members);
    }, error => {
      this.alertifyService.error(error);
    });
  }

  searchMember(query: string) {
    const filteredMembers = (query) ?
      this.members.filter(p => p.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) :
      this.members;
      this.initializeTable(filteredMembers);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does every participant have a `firstName` value?

Comment: can you please post more code especially from the component ? for example show us the `filter`, `participants `, `onInit` etc

Comment: @Dr.Nio, I have addedd full component.ts code in the post. Hope that helps.

Comment: @DeborahK, you're right. I realized that some participants did not have first name. So I needed to check that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend to separate your code in small blocks, that will help you to debug correctly and you should verify that firstName exist in the current object before use it

```
searchParticipant(query: string) {
  let filteredParticipants = [];
  if (query) {
    filteredParticipants = this.participants.filter(p => {
      if (p.firstName && p.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
  }

  this.initializeTable(filteredParticipants);
}
```

Comment: Your code has some syntax errors, but I modified and implemented in my project. The issue was I needed to check the first name then apply the filter.